# Displaying labels for grouped datasets in ChartJS clustered column graph

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

Not sure how to even define this question, so bear with me!

First, I want to display multiple unrelated datasets, side by side.

Second, for each dataset, I'd like to have column-based lables (default for each column), then an overall "grouped" label for the dataset.

[image]

I can "fake" the appearance of this chart by entering a "zero" column entry, creating the gap between the "datasets" I have (even though in ChartJS is just one dataset).

The text line one is default behaviour with ChartJS to display the column label. However getting a "grouped" label to appear is beating me! What I've ended up doing is generating the chart label-less, then doing some funky HTML hacks to get the labels back with the grouped text I need. This approach is not scalable.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? Doesn't have to be ChartJS powered.

Comment: Update: Good ol' Excel is calling this chart type "clustered column", which is nice! :D

Comment: Hey LeadMagnet, welcome to StackOverflow!  I edited your title - hopefully makes it a little more clear.  Please be aware that people are probably going to want to see what you've already tried (make sure to post your code).

Comment: Thanks! Whatever works!

I can post code, if ya really wanna see it. As I said, what I've done so far is just add a zero entry to a standard bar chart to fake the grouping I need.

Currently looking at ChartJS dataset controllers as a possible solution.